# magnific-popup ajax login form loading and submission to php file than show sucess message

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

Can magnific-popup ajax be used to open login form and then to pass values to php process file and once login is done it should show login success message. Is it possible to Ajaxify changing of content within the same single pop up by doing the entire process within the popup? Thanks.

Comment: Where's all your code attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to all of your questions is: **YES**

Comment: I have been trying to get the magnific popup ajax box to show login form. It seems that form appears but as soon as I click anywhere in form or ajax body, it disappears. below is the code

 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
 type: 'ajax',
 alignTop: false,
 closeOnContentClick: false,
 overflowY: 'scroll'
 });
 });

<a class=".ajax-popup-link" href="result.php">try me</a><br>

Answer (score 0):

As a person who has frequently been downvoted in the past, I can say you need to be more specific in your questions. As in

"How do I pass values to this PHP file"

```
<code examples>
```

Code examples /JSFiddle is always key for anyone to be able to truly help you! :)

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
 type: 'ajax',
 alignTop: false,
 closeOnContentClick: false,
 overflowY: 'scroll'
 });
 });

<a class=".ajax-popup-link" href="result.php">try me</a><br>